# How can a complex funtion be real-differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Currently, I am trying to understand when is a function $f=u+iv: Ω→\mathbb{C}$ is complex differentiable on $Ω$, with the clause that the functions $u$ and $v$ satisfy the scalar Cauchy-Riemann equations. The sources say, the function $f$ has to be $\mathbb{R}-$differentiable. What does that mean?

Comment: If $\displaystyle\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\to f'(x)$ as $h\to0$, real differentiability has $h$ approaching $0$ through the reals while complex differentiability has $h$ approaching $0$ through all paths of complex numbers. Easy.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> _Real-differentiable_ means "in the sense of a mapping from the real plane to the real plane." Further details about the distinction between real and complex differentiability can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4373023/complex-derivative-vs-two-variable-derivative-requiring-same-limit-from-differe) (in addition to many other similar questions and answers).

Comment: @Jam you are incorrect.  Your condition would only say that the partial derivative with respect to x exists everywhere.  The definition of real differentiability is that the function can be approximated locally by a real linear map.

Answer (score 1):

The complex numbers are a 1 dimensional complex vector space, but they are also a 2 dimensional real vector space.

Given a function $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, we say that $f$ is real-differentiable at a point $p$ if there exists a real linear map $L:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ so that

$$
f(p+h) = f(p) + L(h) + E(h)
$$

Where

$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|E(h)|}{|h|} = 0
$$

If we instead require that the map $L$ be complex linear, then we obtain the definition of complex differentiability.

You can prove that if the function $f(x+iy) = u(x+iy)+iv(x+iy)$ is real differentiable, then the matrix of $L$ with respect to the basis 1,i is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If the function happens to be complex differentiable, then this matrix must represent multiplication by a complex number.  This is exactly the statement that the Cauchy Riemann equations must hold.